# Traveling by Train from Dhaka to Kolkata

Tags: trains, indian-railways, bangladeshi-citizens

I am a Bangladeshi citizen and I am holding a Bangladeshi Passport. Recently I got visa for visit to India and I want to travel by train.

Is there any specific regulation for traveling by train to India?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a regular sticker visa for India of any type you can enter using the train. The only exception is if there is any additional remark on your sticker visa that prevents train entry into India or only allows entry by air. The wordings for this exception differ from case to case but can vary between "Entry by train not allowed" to "Valid for entry by air only".